# Show result in a UITextField

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I am facing a problem with fill (text field) with result which requested from MySql via a PHP file. I did change the PHP file to a different ways but I still have the same problem.

Her is my PHP file:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="UserName"; // Mysql username 
$password="PassWord"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="DataBase"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Table"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

mysql_set_charset('utf8');

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$userName = $_REQUEST['userName'];
$userName = stripslashes($userName);
$userName = mysql_real_escape_string($userName);
$userName = html_entity_decode($_REQUEST['userName'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE userName = '$userName'";

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //5
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);


$count = 1;
$items;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $item['userName'] = $row['userName'];
    $item['emailAddress'] = $row['emailAddress'];

    $items[$count] = $item;
}

//echo json_encode($items);
echo json_encode($items, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Her is the Objective-c code (in Xcode):

```
- (id)makeURLRequestWithString:(NSString *)url {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                            timeoutInterval:10];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    // Make synchronous request
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                            returningResponse:&response
                                                        error:&error];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    if (urlData) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];
        return dict;
    } else return error;
}
```

Her is the code when I press the button:

```
- (IBAction)callJson:(id)sender {

    dispatch_queue_t jsonParsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("jsonParsingQueue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{ //Do request on another queue to prevent it from blocking UI
        id result = [self makeURLRequestWithString:@"http:/MyWebSite.com/PHPFile.php?userName=123"];
        NSLog(@"%@", result);

      // Her where I need to fill my text with info from the above url
        // self.emailAddress.text = ...............What to do her?


    });
}
```

Her is the result from Xcode:

```
{
    1 =     {
        emailAddress = "123@hotmail.com";
        userName = "123";
    };
}
```

The request shows the data, but I don't no how to fill the text with it.
I hope my question is clear.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display the username and/or email but unsure of how to get the text out?

Comment: yes, I need the result to be in a text field

Comment: @ahmed.s.alkaabi > What result? Email/username or both in two different textfield? What do you want?

Comment: In two different text field, The userName in a (text1) and the emailAddress in (text2)

Comment: Consider using AFnetworking for REST API calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the results into an NSDictionary/NSArray with NSJSONSerialization. If your result is a data object, you could call

```
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&err];
NSString *email = [[results objectForKey:@"1"] objectForKey:@"emailAddress"];
```

Then to stick it in the textbox you would just use the normal code

```
textbox.text = email;
```

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, I see now you have already thrown in the Parsing JSON in the above method. So when you are calling `self.emailAddress.text` You are still in a background thread with your dispatch_async() call. So in order to make it actually update the text box you would do the following right after you get id result =...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), $^{
   self.emailAddress.text = [[result objectForKey:@"1"] objectForKey:@"emailAddress"];
});
```

Another tip, it's a little weird that your JSON data starts at index 1, if it is going to be an ordered list (eg. 1, 2, 3, 4..) you should format it like an array. I think I see the problem in your PHP, it should look more like this (assuming I understand what you are trying to do):

```
...
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    var $tmp = [];    
    $tmp['userName'] = $row['userName'];
    $tmp['emailAddress'] = $row['emailAddress'];
    $items[] = $tmp;
}
...
```

That will output an array of Items from the database with dictionaries containing the emails and usernames like so
[
  {'email1', 'user1'},
  {'email2', 'user2'}
]

But if you do it that way, you'd have to change your code above in the makeUrlrequestwithstring method to return an array like this:

```
if (urlData) {
        NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];
        return arr;
    } else return error;
```

Then your output code would look like this (assuming you wanted the first item in the query result)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), $^{
       self.emailAddress.text = [result[0] objectForKey:@"emailAddress"];
    });
```

Comment: That's what my code does, it parses the JSON so you can get the email address and put it in your text box. If you just want to put the whole result in a textbox I think you already have the code for that, but I don't think that's what you're asking.

Comment: it is exactly what I want, But I have problem with using your code where to use it? I am new in this

Comment: why don't you try `setText` method on textField?